# Making My Own CLI(Command Line Interface) Using CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, command-line-interface

In the previous accepted reply I found the following code. [source](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41121/making-a-bat-batch-command-line-interface#new-answer?s=0857a55f8b4e43c1a1d4b13236169370): https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41121/making-a-bat-batch-command-line-interface#new-answer?s=0857a55f8b4e43c1a1d4b13236169370

### Title: Making a .bat batch command-line interface

```
:: Define all valid commands: make sure there is a space between each command
:: and also one at beginning and end
set "commands= something echo exit "

:input.get

:: Clear the existing value in case user hits <Enter> without entering anything
set "input="

:: Get the next command
set /p "input=COMMAND\>"

:: Parse command into command and arguments.
for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%A in ("!input!") do (

  REM check if command is valid (not case sensitive) and act accordingly
  if "!commands: %%A =!" equ "!commands!" (
    echo Invalid command: %%A
  ) else if /i %%A equ exit (
    exit /b
  ) else (
    call :%%A %%B
  )
)
echo(
goto input.get


:something
echo Doing something with Arg1=[%1] and Arg2=[%2]
exit /b

:echo
echo(%*
exit /b
```

If I want to add one more command how to do that?
like if user write 'pop' then he/she wile get the reply like bellow:

```
You wrote pop
```

Now how can I this by editing this.

Comment: I guess you'll have to do two things: 1. add the new command to the commands list in line 3, and 2. add a label :pop at the end and do an echo "You wrote pop" like in :something or :echo.

Comment: The original linked answer pretty much told you exactly what to do.

Comment: stackexchange and stackoverflow are all the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two simple things:

1. add `pop` to your list of valid commands

   ```
   set "commands= something echo exit pop "
   ```
2. add the code to process the command as a new callable subroutine

   ```
   :pop
   echo You wrote pop
   exit /b
   ```